# php сервер не видит post запросы

Tags: php

код в единственном файле на сервере -

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
print_r($_POST)
```

код по которому пытаюсь отправить post запрос -

```
function f() {
        fetch("http://reinaght.xyz/",{
            method:"POST",
            header:{
                'Content-type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({action: 1})
        })
        .then(responce => responce.text())
        .then(responce => {
            console.log(responce)
        })
    }
f()
```

Я пытаюсь отправить простой post запрос на сервер и убедится, что сервер читает, что я отправляю через post, но вместо ответа я получаю - "Array ()".
Я только недавно начал изучать php и не понимаю, что нужно сделать, чтобы прочитать в php файле то, что отправляют из js

Comment: Потому что отсылка таких данных с таким типом содержимого неверна, смотрите [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35325370/how-do-i-post-a-x-www-form-urlencoded-request-using-fetch)

Comment: потому что вам application/json тогда слать надо и получать не в пост а в пхп://инпут